# How to include sample sizes of each node in H2O tree visualization

Tags: python, h2o, mojo

I am working on the visualization of a regression tree using H2O in Python. https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/display_tree_mojo/DisplayTreeMojoH2O.ipynb

The example above provides a method of using PrintMOJO. However the output figure does not include the sample size of each node (and the average value of the node). In SKLearn the sample size and average values are included but I don't know how to integrate them in H2O.

This is what I am looking for:
http://www.netinstructions.com/content/images/2015/07/decision-tree-visualized.png

Any idea?

I looked for a lot of resources but I don't know which option or variable should I play with to make that happen. If I switch to R does that make things easier?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I was looking at the PrintMojo for DRF and could not find any options for node-counts.  It may be, and I don't know this is the case, that there is no option to enable node counts in the display.

Comment: Is there any other package that I can use for that? I went for H2O as I need categorical analysis. Other than that I don't have any preference on the packages.

Comment: Tensor flow might be able to do really well here. I think it has much more elaborate graphic representation capabilities. There is a book called hands on machine learning with psychic learning tensor flow that has a fair bit of that in it. You could check it out in the library and get some mileage there.

Comment: Scikit-learn, not psychic. Darn Siri.

Answer (score 0):

If you supply the “—detail” parameter to the PrintMojo tree printing tool you will get more information out.

In particular, you will see the weight of each node, which is the sum of row weights that passed in to the node.  (The default weight for each row is 1.0, but you can change it on a row-by-row basis by providing a weight column.)

The source code for PrintMojo is here:

- https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-genmodel/src/main/java/hex/genmodel/tools/PrintMojo.java